# Java reading file content

Tags: java, button, actionlistener, jfilechooser, fileopendialog

Hey I need to read a text file content and store it (for example inside a string). The problem is, that I don't want to read a certain file, like here:

```
btnOpen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        FileReader reader = new FileReader( "TextAreaLoad.txt" );
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
                        edit.read( br, null );
                        br.close();
                        edit.requestFocus();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e2) { System.out.println(e2); }
                }
}
```

I would like to get contains of a file, choosed with fileChooser, like:

```
btnOpen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //Handle open button action.
                if (e.getSource() == btnOpen) {
                    int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(Main.this);

                    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();

                    } 
                    else {

                    }
               } 
            }
});
```

Question is: how?

Comment: I don't see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have the `File`, you can create a `FileReader` from it and use it just like you do in your first example. `FileReader` has a constructor that takes a `File` as a parameter. But I would move the call to the `close` method into a finally block.

Comment: So simply and yet so helpful! Thanks :)